# Deleting files in Windows, according to a naming convention, using Python

Tags: python, html, windows, python-2.7, pycharm

I am trying to write a program in Python. I want to be able to point this program to a directory, let's say `C:\User\Desktop\Folder`. This Folder contains two types of HTML file, for one the filename ends in `...abc.html` and the other it ends in `...def.html`. I want to recursively delete, within all folders and sub-folders of `C:\User\Desktop\Folder`, which end in `def.html`. What is the best way of doing this ?

I have tried to do it like so :

```
import os
def deleteFiles(path):
 files = os.listdir(path)
 for f in files:
  if not os.path.isdir(f) and "DEF.html" in f:
   os.remove(f)
  if os.path.isdir(f):
   deleteFiles(path + "/" + f)

deleteFiles("C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\TestCode")
```

Running this in PyCharm, however, I get an error :

```
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'testDEF.html'
```

What have I done wrong here ?

Comment: You should use `os.path.join` to create the full file name and location (you should also be careful with backslashes in Python strings).

Comment: If you really want to use backslashes in python strings, create a raw string:
`r"this\is\a\raw\string\and the backslashes\won't be \\escaped`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change `os.remove(f)` to `os.remove(os.path.join(path, f))`

Btw, it is not a recommended best practice to create hard coded path.
Ie you should create your path this way:

```
deleteFiles(os.path.join(path, f))
deleteFiles(os.path.join('C:', 'Users', 'ADMIN', 'Desktop', 'TestCode')
```

so that your separators ('/' or '\') will fit your platform automatically.